# convert a TTF file to base64 on javascript server-side

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to put a TTF file in my react js project and convert it to base64 on javascript, But all solution that I founded was client-side and used FileReader() function. Is there any server-side way to do that?

Comment: What are you using server-side to serve files to clients? Do you have a backend or is it a static site?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, where some people vote down new posts without ever give an explanation. :(

Comment: https://icodealot.com/convert-data-to-base64-in-nodejs/

Comment: @phuzi : I am using syncfusion grid component on react js, for export to pdf grids with Persian font I need to convert TTF file to base64